# How to get an array without duplicates from object elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object with groups (as an example). Each group object contains one `header` id and multiple `trigger` ids.
I want to get an array of all the triggers of all groups without duplicates.

An example would be this:

```
const groups = {
  group1: { header: 9, trigger: [10,11] },
  group2: { header: 15, trigger: [11, 17] }
}
```

Currently, I am doing it like so:

```
const triggers = Array.from(groups, x => x.trigger);
```

This gives me the following result: `[[10,11],[11,17]]`

My plan is to get something like this: `[10,11,17]`. They don't have to be sorted but the duplicates (in this case `11`) has to be removed. Is there any fast way of doing it? Otherwise I would loop through this array now and then concat to a new array but I think there is a faster and better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method

```js
const groups = {
  group1: { header: 9, trigger: [10,11] },
  group2: { header: 15, trigger: [11, 17] }
}
const triggers = [...new Set(Object.values(groups).flatMap(x=>x.trigger))]

console.log(triggers)
```

Comment: Little addition from my side since I have no access to the newest ECMAScript.
I am still using ES6 but your answer gave me enough advice to make a little workaround. It's ugly as hell but it works.
So if anyone needs this answer but for ES6, here is the code:
`const triggers = [...new Set([].concat.apply([], Array.from(groups, x => x.trigger)))];`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty quick way using a `Set`

```js
const groups = {
  group1: { header: 9, trigger: [10,11] },
  group2: { header: 15, trigger: [11, 17] }
}

const addGroupTrigger = (triggersSet, [, group]) => {
  for (const trigger of group.trigger) {
    triggersSet.add(trigger)
  }
  return triggersSet
}

console.log(
  Array.from(Object.entries(groups).reduce(addGroupTrigger, new Set()))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `Array.from` as in your code, I can't make it work like you said.

Btw, I have this snippet, take a look to see if it helps:

```
const groups = {
  group1: { header: 9, trigger: [10,11] },
  group2: { header: 15, trigger: [11, 17] }
}
var arr = []
Object.keys(groups).forEach(function (key) {
    arr = arr.concat(groups[key].trigger);
});
console.log('Array with DUP: ', arr);
var set = new Set(arr);
arr = Array.from(set);
console.log('Array without DUP: ', arr);
```